# Force gdb to load local shared library iso target library

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gdbserver

I'am using gdbserver and gdb on host to debug arch ARM application linked to shared library.
I have a copy of the Library on host with symbols and I want gdb to load the local library instead of the remote one.
Changing the sysroot from target: to local path cannot solve the issue. Always gdb load Library from target.
My question is how can I force gdb to use local library iso the remote one ?

Comment: did you set `sysroot` before start your program ?

Comment: Yes I did and I already verified via show sysroot

Comment: What is the output from `info shared`?

Comment: (gdb) info shared
No shared libraries loaded at this time.